# lockNow() in broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, locking, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

it seems that i get an error when i try to use LockNow() in the broadcast receiver. can anyone help me.

```
public class Onlockreceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

LockSettings lockactivity;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
lockactivity.mdevicepolicymanager.lockNow();    

} 
}
```

The error message :

> 12-31 03:14:16.322: D/AndroidRuntime(27478): Shutting down VM 12-31    03:14:16.322: W/dalvikvm(27478): threadid=1: thread exiting with    uncaught exception (group=0x41b0d378) 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    receiver com.example.settings2.Onlockreceive:    java.lang.NullPointerException 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2257)    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138) 12-31    03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-31    03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 12-31    03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-31    03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 12-31    03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-31 03:14:16.332:    E/AndroidRuntime(27478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    com.example.settings2.Onlockreceive.onReceive(Onlockreceive.java:15)    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2250)    12-31 03:14:16.332: E/AndroidRuntime(27478): ... 10 more

---

My problem is similar to this one [same problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G2CT7n5MRp8).. but i don't understand how to fix it

this is the code i use to call the broadcast receiver

```
private void setupAlarm(int seconds,boolean s) {



// Finish the currently running activity
   // MainActivity.this.finish();

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Onlockreceive.class);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
     LockSettings.this, 0, intent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


  Log.d(TAG, "Setup the alarm");

  // Getting current time and add the seconds in it
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

if (s == true){
  //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
  //alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(type, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, operation)
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent   );
}else if (s == false)
{
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `lockactivity` or `mdevicepolicymanager` is `null`. This is not surprising, as your process may well have been terminated before the `BroadcastReceiver` got control.

**Static data members are only a cache**. Do not rely upon them. And most certainly **do not put an `Activity` in a static data member**, as you are leaking a lot of memory by doing so.

You can use the `Context` passed into `onReceive()` to retrieve a `DevicePolicyManager` and call `lockNow()`.

**UPDATE**

Here is the revised class, complete with better formatting and case:

```
public class OnLockReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {  
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ((DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE)).lockNow();
  } 
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more on how can i use context to retrieve DevicePolicyManager

Comment: @Azharan: You would do it the same way you got the `DevicePolicyManager` in your activity, assuming that `mdevicepolicymanager` is supposed to be a `DevicePolicyManager`. You would call `(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE)` on the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`.

Comment: sorry to ask again.. i  posted the code i use to call the broadcast receiver.. Do you mean that i need to modify this part 'PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
     LockSettings.this, 0, intent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
'

Comment: @Azharan: No. That is not where you are crashing. You are crashing in your `onReceive()` method of your `Onlockreceive` `BroadcastReceiver`. In the `onReceive()` method of your `Onlockreceive` `BroadcastReceiver`, use `getSystemService()` to get a `DevicePolicyManager`, then call `lockNow()` on the `DevicePolicyManager`. You can call `getSystemService()` on the `Context` that is passed into the `onReceive()` method of your `Onlockreceive` `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService (Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
  dpm.lockNow(); 
 }
 private DevicePolicyManager getSystemService(String devicePolicyService) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return dpm;
 }
` i initialize dpm as DevicePolicyManager.. can you see any problem with this one cause i still got error

Comment: thank very much for your help.. i really appreciate it.. i will go and deepen my knowledge in java. thanks again